# Sending data to the backend

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used AngularJS and I am a beginner .

I have tried to send the text field and drop down value to the back end (Java). I have successfully sent the text with out no problem. But I have failed to send the drop down value to the back end.

When I turn on the debugger mode in browser it successfully showed the text field value which is  "firstName":"mike" but drop down value showed me `"stream" ""`. Can you please give me a solution?

Comment: provide some of your code...and use network tab to see actual outgoing request

Answer (score 2):

You send JSON object by using `POST` or `PUT` methods.

sample example will be

```
  $http({
         url: 'Home/Index',
         method: "POST",
         data: user 
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        // success
    }, 
     function(response) { // optional
        // failed
    });
```

You do not need to convert model objects to JSON the angular does that for you.

see the fiddle for working example

http://jsfiddle.net/bkUEu/458/

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge,you cannot send object directly,you need to change the object into json.

JSON.stringify(obj);

Answer (score 0):

Use valid JSON format to send data from front-end to back-end,

```
{"firstName":"mike", "stream":"aaa"}
```